# WPF Loop with DataGrid Rows

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, datagrid

First: this is my code at the moment

```
    class Plan
    {
        public string Linie { get; set; }
        public string Kurs { get; set; }
        public string Abfahrt { get; set; }
        public string Von { get; set; }
        public string Nach { get; set; }
        public string Ankunft { get; set; }
        public string Pause { get; set; }

        public Plan(string Linie, string Kurs, string Abfahrt, string Von, string Nach, string Ankunft, string Pause)
        {
            this.Linie = Linie;
            this.Kurs = Kurs;
            this.Abfahrt = Abfahrt;
            this.Von = Von;
            this.Nach = Nach;
            this.Ankunft = Ankunft;
            this.Pause = Pause;
        }

    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Plan> _items = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Plan>();
    Plan.ItemsSource = _items;
```

So: I want a loop, that do something foreach row. So, as example: A loop that show a MessageBox, which contains each cell (I mean [as example] the Linie of the seleceted row an so on)

I am happy about each answer!
Thank a lot!

Comment: unclear question, try to explain this line :  `Plan.ItemsSource = _items;`

Comment: please clarify "a loop, that do something foreach row". Do you want to show messagebox everytime the user selects a row? or when each row is loaded and shown?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of  `Plan`.

To create list:

```
List<Plan> ListPlan=new List<Plan>();
ListPlan.Add(new Plan("","","",...);
```

To read list:

```
foreach (Plan p in ListPlan)
{
MessageBox.Show(p.Linie)
}
```